# Problem with starting IDLE

Tags: python, idle-python

I have trouble with starting IDLE. I get the following error message.

> IDLE's subprocess didn't make connection. Either IDLE can't start a subprocess or personal firewall software is blocking the connection.

Is my firewall blocking the process, or is it some other problems that appear?

Comment: Not sure what and why IDLE would have to do with your firewall. What is the context?

Comment: i don't konw about it,but it worked previously.

Comment: Not really an answer that I find logical, but it seems it helped OP: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29567051/python-error-idles-subprocess-didnt-make-connection-either-idle-cant-start Also interesting: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=176463 <-- something like that happened to me once, different error though.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a name conflict between a python file stored in your home directory and file that's being used by the python. I solved this by moving all python files in my home directory to a newly created folder.

```
mkdir python_files
mv *py ./python_files/
```